# ERC20 Token transfer

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to send ERC20 token to a different address.
I have stored Ethereum and ERC20 on the same wallet but with different address.

For Eg : At one Address am having 2.5 SKB (8 decimals)
on the another address am having 0.1 ETH.

Si when i try to withdraw the same 2.5 SKB am getting insufficient funds gas * price + value

here is my data parameters

```
        [from] => 0xfrom_address
        [contract] => 0xcontarct_address
        [value] => 0xee6b280 (2.5)
        [to] => 0xtoaddress
        [data] =>0xdata
        [gasPrice] => 0x77359400 (2000000000)
        [gasLimit] => 0x15f90 (90000)
        [gas] => 0x5208 (21000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make a transaction, including token transfers, the address containing the tokens must have enough ether to pay for the maximum possible transaction fee.

The maximum fee is `gasPrice*gasLimit`. Move at least that much ether to the address in which your tokens are.

Comment: So , i should have ETH balance on the same address where i have token?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: ok , let me try and come back here